# Does the cloudstorage extension generate a URL after file uploads?

Tags: ckan

I currently exploring Ckan for data cataloging and publishing and as it doesn't handle large files upload well, I'm using the [ckanext-cloudstorage](https://github.com/TkTech/ckanext-cloudstorage) to push the files to S3.

However when creating a resource using the resource_create API, I noticed that the download URL is not generated.

If I disable the cloudstorage extension and use the local storage, a download link is generated.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

ckanext-cloudstorage does not populate the the download URL because it needs to generate them dynamically when the file is requested to support features such as signed URLs (to allow temporary access to a file).

You should instead use the download URL whenever you try to link to a file, since this will ask you to login if needed and if not it'll 301 you to the real URL. By default it's `/<package_id>/resources/<resource_id>/download`.